# Positive or negative meaning of 'weren't I...' expression

Tags: phrase-meaning

A simplified sentence context would be like following:

'If I wasn't lucky enough, something bad would've happened to me.'

I am trying to reshape the sentence as following.

'Something bad would've happened to me, weren't I lucky enough.'

So I am trying to understand if I use a concept correctly.

*Does "...weren't I lucky enough..." have a positive meaning of "if I **was** lucky enough" or a negative meaning of "if I **wasn't** lucky enough"?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the proper construction is rooted in the [subjunctive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/when-to-use-the-subjunctive) (see point 5), in which case the correct sentence would be

> **Were I not** lucky enough, something bad would've happened to me.

In which case, the so-called "positive" sentence with opposite meaning would be (though its meaning is not at all positive)

> **Were I** lucky enough, something **good** would've happened to me.

which indicates a deficiency in luck that resulted in bad (or, at least, not good) things.

Be careful when pairing structures from the indicative (*I **was** lucky*, *I **wasn't** lucky*) and subjunctive (***Were I*** lucky, ***Were I not*** lucky) moods, as the situations they describe differ in actuality.

Comment: In my specific case, key points are "I was lucky" and "Nothing bad happened". So in this case, I should use your first example as a reference, right? Should I try having 'lucky' part in front of the sentence?

Comment: @VadzimSavenok Yes. Both your key points are highlighted in the first example. Be aware that you can also write the sentence _Something bad would've happened to me **were I not lucky enough**_ and it would still be correct.

Comment: Oh, so in my restructured case, I was using it correctly, just a shortened version from were not to weren't.

Comment: @VadzimSavenok Your positioning of the words _were_, _I_, and _not_ were incorrect, but your thinking was correct.

Comment: So, that was an incorrect shortening?

Comment: @VadzimSavenok Essentially, yes.